# Determine number or character in textfile C

Tags: c, gcc, text-files, file-handling

I have a textfile with these following numbers and characters inside of it.

```
36@xL!?\8
28?&gt;\4
42&lt;pX%7
37@#5
31kL%^?&gt;\&lt;#%5
```

Now, i want to get the first integer which is 36 and subtract it on the last integer which is 8. I want to do this line by line.

Comment: Use `fgets` and `sscanf`, or just `fscanf`.

Comment: @lurker i know that functions but i want a way on how to get it using that functions

Comment: @lurker i want to get the first and the last integer and i want to disregard the characters/symbols that is in the middle of it

Comment: "i know that functions" --> Post the code you have tried, else you are simply asking someone else to do your work.

Comment: Then use `fgets` to read each line into a buffer, and then use `strtol` (with the `endptr` parameter to walk-down the string converting digits into integers) until you reach the end of the line.

Comment: Can any of your numbers be negative? Say a line with `"37@#-5"`? If so, you need another solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to read in the line, parse the numbers at the beginning and end, then convert them to integers. Here is a simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
    FILE *file = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    char line[256];

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file))
    {
    char num[15];
    int firstNumber = 0;
    int secondNumber = 0;

    line[strcspn(line, "\r\n")] = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < 256; x++)
    {
        if (isdigit(line[x]))
        {
            num[x] = line[x];
        } 
        else 
        {
            num[x] = 0;
            break;
        }
    }        
    firstNumber = atoi(num);

    int length = strlen(line);
    int ndx = 0;
    while (length >=0 && isdigit(line[length - 1]))
    {
        num[ndx] = line[length - 1];
        ndx++;
        length--;
    }
    num[ndx] = 0;
    secondNumber = atoi(num);

    printf("%d - %d = %d\n", firstNumber, secondNumber, firstNumber - secondNumber);
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: great idea!. thanks

Comment: How would `"-45"` be interpreted? (as `45` or `-45`)?

Answer (score 0):

You already have a good answer for the file posted as part of your question, however, the result of `first - last` will be incorrect if you line of text contains a `'-'` sign before the digits indicating a negative signed value. All of the C string to integer conversions will accept a leading `+/-` before the value to be converted indicating a positive or negative number. If your input can contain negative values, you need to preserve the `'-'` sign by including that with the digits to be converted. For example if your input file was:

```
36@xL!?\-8
28?&gt;\4
-42&lt;pX%7
37@#-5
31kL%^?&gt;\&lt;#%5
```

The answers would be quite different with `-8, -42` and `-5` as the integer values from the file. Now if that isn't a possibility based on your specific assignment, then you can skip preserving the `'-'`, but for read-world text conversion to signed values, it is critical.

One way of finding the beginning of a signed number for conversion in a string is simply scan forward in the string (similar to what `strpbrk()` would do) looking for either a beginning digit or `'-'` (whichever occurs first). If the `'-'` occurs first, you then check that the next character is a digit. You can do it with a simple loop, e.g.

```
/** scan forward in 'p' to find beginning of next valid signed integer.
 *  returns pointer to beginning of signed int on success, NULL otherwise.
 */
const char *nextdigit (const char *p)
{
    while (*p) {
        /* if digit or +/- followed by a digit */
        if (isdigit(*p) ||
            ((*p == '-' || *p == '+') && isdigit(*(p + 1))))
            return p;
        p++;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Once you have found the beginning of a digit, then you need to use a function that provides error-checking on the conversion. `atoi()` provides zero diagnostics for the conversion and will silently return `0` as a valid number for the conversion of `atoi("my cow");` You will have no indication whether digits were actually converted or whether the result exceeds the storage size for all integer types. `atoi()` issues no errors at all, even if provided with a 200 digit string as input. At minimum, use `sscanf` that will at least provide a `yes/no`, `true/false` as to whether a valid conversion took place, or better, use `strtol` which provides full error reporting on the conversion.

For example, you can write a short function that take the address of a pointer to string, use `nextdigit()` function above, and then use `strtol` to fully validate the result, setting `errno` for validation back in the caller on any error and returning the results of the integer conversion (or `0` on error) as follows:

```
/** returns next integer in string pointed to by p, or sets errno and returns
 *  zero on error.
 */
int getnextint (char **p)
{
    int nextint = 0;

    errno = 0;
    if ((*p = (char*)nextdigit(*p))) {
        char *endptr;
        long tmp = strtol (*p, &endptr, 0);

        if (*p == endptr) { /* validate digits converted */
            fputs ("error: no digits converted.\n", stderr);
            errno = EINVAL;
        }
        else if (errno)     /* validate conversion */
            fputs ("error: over/underflow occurred.\n", stderr);
        /* validate tmp is in range of integer */
        else if (INT_MIN <= tmp && tmp <= INT_MAX)
            nextint = tmp;
        else {
            fputs ("error: value exceeds range of int.\n", stderr);
            errno = ERANGE;
        }
        *p = (char*)nextdigit(endptr);
    }
    else
        errno = EINVAL;     /* if no digits found, set EINVAL */

    return nextint;
}
```

(**note:** the address of the pointer is passed so that the pointer can be updated within the function to the beginning of the next integer to convert in the string (or `NULL` if no more remain)

To complete the example, you can add the needed headers and write a short `main()` to read from your filename provided as the first argument (or read from `stdin` by default if no argument is provided) that will locate the first and last integers in each line and subtract `first - last` outputting the result:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* for strtol   */
#include <string.h> /* for strcspn */
#include <limits.h> /* for INT_MIN/INT_MAX */
#include <errno.h>  /* for errno    */
#include <ctype.h>  /* for isdigit */

#define ARSZ  100
#define MAXC 1024
...                                  /* insert functions here */
int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[MAXC] = "";
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {     /* read each line of input */
        int arr[ARSZ] = {0};
        char *p = buf;
        size_t n = 0;
        buf[strcspn(buf, "\r\n")] = 0;
        while (n < ARSZ && p) {
            arr[n] = getnextint (&p);
            if (!errno)
                n++;
        }
        if (n > 1)
            printf ("%-19s  :  % 2d - % 2d = % 3d\n", 
                    buf, *arr, arr[n-1], *arr - arr[n-1]);
        else
            fprintf (stderr, "%zu integer(s) in: '%s'\n", n, buf);
    }
    if (fp != stdin)   /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);
}
```

**Example Input Files**

Your original input file:

```
$ cat dat/last-first.txt
36@xL!?\8
28?&gt;\4
42&lt;pX%7
37@#5
31kL%^?&gt;\&lt;#%5
```

And another with negative values and additional extraneous lines:

```
$ cat dat/last-first2.txt
36@xL!?\-8
28?&gt;\4
-42&lt;pX%7
Nothing to see!
37@#-5
31kL%^?&gt;\&lt;#%5
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/fgets_strtol_any_last-first dat/last-first.txt
36@xL!?\8            :   36 -  8 =  28
28?&gt;\4            :   28 -  4 =  24
42&lt;pX%7           :   42 -  7 =  35
37@#5                :   37 -  5 =  32
31kL%^?&gt;\&lt;#%5  :   31 -  5 =  26
```

When run on the file with negative values and the extraneous line:

```
$ ./bin/fgets_strtol_any_last-first dat/last-first2.txt
36@xL!?\-8           :   36 - -8 =  44
28?&gt;\4            :   28 -  4 =  24
-42&lt;pX%7          :  -42 -  7 = -49
0 integer(s) in: 'Nothing to see!'
37@#-5               :   37 - -5 =  42
31kL%^?&gt;\&lt;#%5  :   31 -  5 =  26
```

As you can see from the result of the subtractions between the different files, it makes a great deal of difference whether you preserve the leading `'-'` when converting signed values. Something to consider going forward.

Look things over and let me know if you have additional questions.