# Read testcase and list of numbers from a file in C

Tags: c

I'm new in C language and I'm really confused on how to read test cases and list of numbers from a file.

Sample input from a file:

```
2
6 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0
3 -2.0 4.0 44.0
```

On  which 2 is the number of test case, in the new line the size and the list of numbers.

Comment: The functions you need are `fopen`, `fscanf`, and `fclose`.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I also get confused in how to read the test case, size and list of numbers

Comment: here is a hint -> each line ends with a '\n' character.

Comment: Declare `int ncases, nnumbers; double val;` The naive way open file, and `if (scanf ("%d", &ncases) != 1) { /* handle error, exit */ }` Then `while (ncases--) { if (scanf ("%d", &nnumbers) != 1) { /* handle error, exit */ } while (nnumbers--) { if (sscanf ("%lf", &val) == 1) printf ("%f\n", val); }`. The recommended way would be to read each line into a buffer (e.g. `#define MAXC 1024` then `char buf[MAXC];` and loop `while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fileptr)) {...` and then parse the values from `buf` with `sscanf()` for `ncases` and then loop with `strtol` and strtod` for each value in the line.

Comment: **note:** above, `scanf()` should be `fscanf (fileptr, ...)` to read from a file rather than from the file redirected on `stdin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Key To All Program Input**

If you learn nothing else from this answer, learn that you cannot use any input function correctly unless you ***check the return*** to ***validate*** the input succeeded and that you have valid input to process going forward in your code. Failure to validate your input will likely invoke *Undefined Behavior* if input fails for any reason and you attempt to access the value that wasn't actually read from input.

**A Simple (but Fragile) Approach**

By far the easiest way to read numeric values from your file is by using a *formatted-input* function (meaning the `scanf()` family of functions). While this is a simple and convenient way to read and convert values from your file -- it is fragile because if the format differs in any way from:

```
testcases
nnumbers val val val ....        /* out to nnumber values */
...
```

or the lines contain extraneous character (like the comment above), the input routine breaks and your program fails to read all values. It is convenient because it is shorter that writing a more robust input method that uses a *line-oriented* approach reading a line at a time into a buffer and then parsing the information you need from that buffer.

(The benefit of a *line-oriented* approach being that the read of the line and parse of the values are *separate* operations, so that any failure in line format (at most) only causes the loss of that one line of data and your read will pickup with the next line. You also have the benefit of being able to validate the read of the line and the parse of the information from that line -- *independently* allowing you to determine exactly where any problem exists)

You start by opening the file you need to read. You can either do that by prompting the user for the filename -- or since the `main()` function takes arguments `(int argc, char **argv)`, simply pass the filename to read as the first argument on the command line.

(where `argc` is your *argument-count* telling you the number of command line arguments present [the first argument is always the program name being run, so the first user-supplied argument is the second in `argv` -- your *argument vector* which is an array of pointers to nul-terminated strings with the first pointer after the last valid argument set to `NULL`. Since C uses zero-based array indexes, the first user-supplied argument is `argv[1]`, the second `argv[2]`, and so on... The name of the program being run is in the first element of the array, `argv[0]`)

A convenient way to handle opening the file is to check if the user supplied a filename as the first argument, and if so, open that file to read your data. If no filename is supplied, then by default you can read from `stdin` (the way most Linux utilities do). For example to open the filename provided as the first argument or read `stdin` by default, you can use a simple *ternary* operator to determine which to open:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int ncases = 0;     /* number of cases to read */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
    ...
```

As with any file operation, you always ***validate*** the file is open for reading before attempting to read from the file-stream, e.g.

```
    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }
```

Now you are at the point where you read the first value from the file, the number of testcases into the `ncases` variable -- using the very first thing you learned in this answer (validate every input):

```
    if (fscanf (fp, "%d", &ncases) != 1) {  /* read/validate ncases */
        fputs ("error: invalid integer value - ncases.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
```

After the read, the file-position indicator will be right before the `'\n'` at the end of line 1 of the file. But since the numeric conversion specifiers for `fscanf()` ignore whitespace, you can simply proceed to read the next number in the file without having to explicitly read/discard the `'\n'`, e.g.

Now that you have `ncases`, you need to loop that many times and read the first integer on each line telling your the number of floating-point values that follow on that same line. You can use a `for (int i = 0; i < ncases; i++)` loop, or you can simply loop `while (ncases--)` to loop `ncases` times -- up to you:

```
    while (ncases--) {          /* loop ncases times */
        int nnumbers = 0;
        if (fscanf (fp, "%d", &nnumbers) != 1) {    /* read/validate nnumbers */
            fputs ("error: invalid integer value - nnumbers.\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
```

Now that you have read `nnumbers` at the beginning of the line for your testcase, you need to loop `nnumbers` times reading and converting the floating-point values. So,

```
        while (nnumbers--) {    /* loop nnumbers times */
            double val = 0.;
            if (fscanf (fp, "%lf", &val) != 1) {    /* read/validate each val */
                fputs ("error: invalid floating-point value.\n", stderr);
                return 1;
            }
            printf (" %.2f", val);                  /* output each val */
        }
```

(**note:** above you cannot test `== 1` and only print the value if the read succeeded. Why? This is where this approach is **FRAGILE**. If instead of a floating-point value, there was something else on the line like `"banannas"`, then a *matching-failure* would occur, nothing is read into `val`, character extraction from the file ceases, so whatever caused the failure will be read again on the next attempted read -- spiraling you off into an infinite loop if you went that route. Which is why a *line-oriented* approach is recommended)

That's it, you have read and printed all your values, you can output a `'\n'` to make sure each line of values is printed on its own line, and then close the file when you are done with it.

(it will automatically be closed on program exit -- but build good habits early, close the file, it won't be long before you are handling file operations many functions deep in your code, and there failure to close the file can lead to eventual exhaustion of file descriptors)

The complete example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int ncases = 0;     /* should be size_t, but let's start with int */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    if (fscanf (fp, "%d", &ncases) != 1) {  /* read/validate ncases */
        fputs ("error: invalid integer value - ncases.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    while (ncases--) {          /* loop ncases times */
        int nnumbers = 0;
        if (fscanf (fp, "%d", &nnumbers) != 1) {    /* read/validate nnumbers */
            fputs ("error: invalid integer value - nnumbers.\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
        while (nnumbers--) {    /* loop nnumbers times */
            double val = 0.;
            if (fscanf (fp, "%lf", &val) != 1) {    /* read/validate each val */
                fputs ("error: invalid floating-point value.\n", stderr);
                return 1;
            }
            printf (" %.2f", val);                  /* output each val */
        }
        putchar ('\n');     /* tidy up with newline */
    }

    if (fp != stdin)   /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your example file in `dat/cases.txt`, you would receive the following output:

```
$ ./bin/fscanf_cases dat/cases.txt
 1.00 2.00 3.00 4.00 5.00 6.00
 -2.00 4.00 44.00
```

This example simply reads each testcase and outputs the values. You would normally store all values for later use, etc... That is left to you. If you have learned nothing else, make sure you have learned to ***check the return*** of every input oriented function you use to ***validate*** your input succeeded and you can then safely proceed to use the input in your code. Let me know if you have further questions.

An example of a *line-oriented* approach for reading integer values can be found here [Determine number or character in textfile C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60276153/3422102)

Answer (score 0):

Use these two lines before using input

```
freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);//redirects standard input 
freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);//redirects standard output
```