# C programming, reading specific lines of code

Tags: c, loops, file

Im very new to C programming, now I'm trying to read a file and use the information from this file in later function. The only thing i want to take from the file is the numbers, i do not want words
the file im reading from has a format of

```
&& hello
3 3
&& world
1
&& welcome
2
3
```

So basically if the line begins with a '&&' it can be disregarded

```
FILE* in = fopen(filename, "r");
if (in == NULL){
perror("Error reading file \n");
}
```

Im unsure on what to do to ensure i only take the lines that dont start with '&&'.
to read the whole file i know i can do a simple while loop of

```
while(( char li = fgetc(in)) != EOF) {
printf("%c", li)
}
```

any help is much appreciated

Comment: There is no simple way to "skip" straight to where you need to go. A common way would be to use `fgets` to read each line, check the first two characters, if `&&` then move on to next line else parse the numbers with `strtok` and `strtol`.

Comment: What is the format of the lines that you want to read numbers from? Do they always start with a digit, are the numbers separated by spaces, are they integers, is there a max count of numbers to be read? For example, what 's supposed to happen for a line that contains `1 2a2z 3,3.3`.

Comment: You can simply scan forward in the string converting integers as found and rejecting all other characters without having to worry about what the line begins with or contains (other than integers), e.g. [Determine number or character in textfile C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60276153/3422102)

Answer (score 0):

To parse integers, in this example `int` is used, but the type depends on the size of the numbers to expect.

This assumes the file is reliably formatted.

[C Playground interactive example](https://cplayground.com/?p=dove-peafowl-chough)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main (void) {
    // be sure to choose the right size of integer
    // depending on the values you can get
    int     n1, n2;
    // same here, buffer size matters
    char    buf[2001];
    
    while (fgets(buf, 2000, stdin) != NULL) {
        
        if (buf[0] == '&' && buf[1] == '&') {
            printf("starts with &&, skipping...\n");
            
            continue;
        }
        
        fscanf(stdin, "%d %d", &n1, &n2);
        printf("Num 1 is %d\n", n1);
        printf("Num 2 is %d\n", n2);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```